# Cisco call manager api to conference a device

Tags: voip, cisco

I'm trying to implement some click to dial functionality as follows:

1. A user finds a number on a webpage (say employee extension)
2. Clicking that extension will dial a phone number that I've picked
3. Upon answering that call, I am immediately "conferenced" into
   calling the number I actualy wanted to dial.

I've done something very similar using a Twilio API but want to use our corporate Cisco Call Manager capabilities instead of paying per minute for this functionality.

The WebDialerSOAP doesn't seem to be able to give me this functionality. I think doing a conference would work but can't find anything to do that.  Possibly an open source call manager wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

why not a FreeSWITCH server alongside the CUCM? It can set up conferences, and it's one of themost programmable products with as much control over API as you want.

It has also an RTMP module, so you can actually run a Flash-based softphone out of your browser

Answer (score 0):

1. Use TAPI3 or JTAPI
2. Connect the code using TSP, and Application user
3. use **CreateCall** function to the number from HTML page with implementing the trigger.
4. use **CreateCall** to the other phone.
5. use `Finish(FINISH_MODE.FM_ASCONFERENCE)` to complete conference.